# Given two defined points A and B, what points X exist such that the vectors AX and BX are orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, 3d, orthogonality

For class I have to find:
Given two points, say A (1, 1, 1) and B (5, 5 ,5), what is the set of points X (x, y, z) that exist such that the vectors AX and BX are orthogonal?

I know that the points X = A and X = B will work because they will cause the AX and BX vectors to be equal to 0, but I cannot get a definite answer beyond that. I'm currently considering the possibility that the answer is somehow all the points on a circle, but I have no idea how I would go about constructing such a circle.

Any tips that point me in the right direction or show what the scale of my answer (2 points, 3 points, infinite points?) should be would be greatly appreciated.

Final update:  Thank you for the concise and useful answers!

I have found that the correct way to answer this question is to take the vectors AX and BX: (1-x, 1-y, 1-z) and (5-x, 5-y, 5-z), find their dot product, and set the resulting equation equal to 0. This gives the equation of a sphere, and all points on the surface of said sphere satisfy the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector $AX$ is $(x-1,y-1,z-1)$ and the vector $BX$ is $(x-5,y-5,z-5)$. You want them to be orthogonal, so $AX\cdot BX=0$. Compute the dot product and then complete squares.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look at [Thales Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

Certainly there are two more points on the perpendicular bisector of the segment $AB$.  (Putting the perpendicular lines in for these two points, you see a square with $AB$ its diagonal.)

Hint:  Pick two points on a circle.  The central angle subtending the arc bounded by those two points is twice the [inscribed angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle) of the chords from those two points to any third point on the circle.  (Thales's theorem is a special case of this.)  If the inscribed angle is a right angle, the central angle is ... and the two chords forming that angle together are a ... of the circle.

Comment: Well, if the inscribed angle is a right angle, the central angle would be 180, and the chords would create a diameter of the circle. Since these are 3D points, would this extend to all points on the surface of a sphere?

Comment: @STH : Certainly, the solution set can be revolved around the line $AB$, so is a surface or volume of revolution.